# Vocabulary Question

Tags: vocabulario

To comment “Incredible that they are still like this.” My attempt: “Increíble que quedan así.” I believe I am being misunderstood . Does quedar lack this’d sense ?

Thank you

Comment: In English, we very, very rarely don't use It's here.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context, even so, *quedar* is not the correct verb for this case.

“Incredible that they are still like this.”

The correct way would be:

### Verbo ser

Long version

> Increíble que ellos aún sean así

Short version

> Increíble que aún sean así

### Verbo continuar (to continue)

Long version

> Increíble que ellos continúen así

Short version

> Increíble que continúen así

### Verbo seguir (to remain)

Long version

> Increíble que ellos sigan así

Short version

> Increíble que sigan así

### Forma compuesta con el verbo ser

> Increíble que continúen siendo así
> Increíble que sigan siendo así

Answer (score 0):

To comment “Incredible that they are still like this.” My attempt: “Increíble que quedan así.”

---

Aunque también es posible usar el verbo "estar" normalmente utilizamos el verbo "mantener" o la forma reflexiva "mantenerse".

> Although it is also possible to use the verb "to be", we
> normally use the verb "**mantener**" or the reflexive form "to
> **mantenerse**"

**Mantener - Mantenerse**

1. Proporcionar el alimento o lo necesario para vivir.
2. **Hacer que una cosa continúe en determinado estado, situación o funcionamiento.**

"Es increíble que el frigorífico **mantenga** tan bien los alimentos después de tantos años de uso".

> **Mantener - Mantenerse**
>
> 1. Provide food or what is necessary to live.
> 2. **Make a thing continue in a certain state, situation or operation.** "It's amazing that the refrigerator keeps food so well after so many
>    years of use."

Traducción: **"Increíble que se mantengan así".** **"Increíble que aún estén así.**

> Translation: “Incredible that they are still like this.” /
> **"Increíble que se mantengan así", "Increíble que aún estén así.**

En general todo dependerá de los contextos;

> In general, everything will depend on the contexts;

- Increíble que se mantengan así de jóvenes.

> - Incredible that they remain so young.

- Increíble que se mantengan en pie estos edificios.

> - Incredible that these buildings remain standing.

- Increíble que se mantengan así de bien.

> - Incredible that they stay this well.

- **Increíble que aún estén así.**

> **- Incredible that they are still like this.**

- Increíble que estén en ese estado de conservación.

> - Incredible that they are in that state of conservation.

---